# Make PHP Pagination from Json data

Tags: php

I have a `PHP curl` request, that returns `json` data.

```
"records": {
                "name": "John;",
                "last_name": "Travolta"
            },
```

I'm able to display this data in `foreach` loop. 
However, it has more than 50 records.

Is it any way for me to make pagination, so i can display 5 records per page?

Note, request with limit doesn't work, it's still returns all data:

```
http://api-request-url?limit=5
```

Comment: Yes, it is called `pagination`.  multiple ways to do it - pure PHP+HTML and page reloads, multiple JavaScript libraries that will do it in-place (single page, no reload), etc. Now that you know what you are looking for, go find some examples and try it

Comment: it depends, does the API have it? if they don't then you're just stuck with that more than 50 and do the batches yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of JS libraries that you can use. I have used pagination.js before and it make this very easy to accomplish.

[pagination.js.org/index.html](http://pagination.js.org/index.html)

For the data source you can use an array, an object, a function or a URL. You can also make an AJAX request to get the data, which might work well with your setup.

Example (from docs):

```
$('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 195],
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = template(data);
        dataContainer.html(html);
    }
});
```